# Is there a limit to how much light can pass through glass?

Tags: visible-light, glass

Let’s say I have a one cubic centimeter of glass. Without going into the details, we know that light passes through this glass with the help of the glass. The glass facilitates light’s transmission through it. The glass does something that enables light to pass.

Because the glass is finite, it seems reasonable to conclude that there must be a limit to the amount of light it can process. Is there a volume limit to the amount of light the glass can process?

Note:
I’m not talking about an intensity limit where Kerr Lensing is a factor. I know that high intensity lasers are able to burn a hole through glass. My question is about a volume limit.

Example:
The cubic centimeter of glass can process one low intensity red laser. What if we add 40 low intensity green lasers and 40 low intensity blue lasers. Will we notice any change to the red beam?

Question:
Is there a limit to the amount of visible light a given volume of glass can transmit?

Comment: "The glass does something that enables light to pass." Not sure what you mean by that.

Comment: The glass lets light pass through. What's unclear about it?

Comment: The "glass does something" part. It implies some active role of the glass, where you say "lets pass", which is a passive role.

Comment: @Lambda: that's an interesting question. Actually I would have prefered you did not add other colors (blue, green) and just asked how much red light could be used, because different colors just make your question more complicated. But anyway I hope someone gives a good answer to your question.

Comment: @noah The way light finds its way through a medium is often debated. The marching band, the emission-remission, hypothesis among others can be found in textbooks and on forums. I purposely chose to personify glass to emphasize that the glass itself plays a role in the transmission of the light. When light is incident on its surface the glass reacts. Without this reaction transmission is not possible. This my be a new way of looking at the process, but I don’t think it is incorrect. The glass reacts to the light. Do you disagree? Isn’t this reaction a property of the glass?

Comment: @Lambda I see, these are good points. I was going to make a simple argument about the band gap being too large to absorb photons into the electronic structure, which would be independent of the number of photons passing through, but you seem to be after a more sophisticated answer which I cannot provide without reading up on it myself.

Comment: @Lambda "When light is incident on its surface the glass reacts. Without this reaction transmission is not possible." No, that's wrong. Actually, the transmission is the highest when the interaction between light and any material is the lowest, generally speaking.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you are talking about is a phenomenon called *Reverse saturable absorption* and it is a non-linear effect that some materials show (for example, see https://aip.scitation.org/doi/full/10.1063/1.2990056). Typically standard glass doesn't have this behavior.

Comment: So a piece of glass can withstand an infinite amount of, say, red light?

Comment: @Exocytosis No, with high enough light intensities any material (glass included) can be destroyed. However, the OP is already aware of that and he's asking a different question. The core of his question is "Is the transmissivity of glass a function of the transmitted intensity?" For intensities below the ablation threshold and for standard glass the answer is no.

Comment: Ok I did not realize the question was about something else but thank you for the answer. I feel I am going to ask a new question regarding just that.