# How can glass be destroyed by red light?

Tags: thermodynamics, optics, visible-light

I was reading this answer and follow up comments:
https://physics.stackexchange.com/a/623227/230132

Alessandro says red light can damage a piece of glass if its intensity is sufficient.

I assumed glass was transparent to red light and I also assumed transparent meant there was no interaction.

Both assumptions may be wrong.

So I started to suspect glass to be a less than perfectly transparent medium to red light and as such, given a sufficient intensity, it will heat and burn. Simple math.

Is this the correct explanation though?

I looked for glass absorption and found this page:
https://www.koppglass.com/blog/optical-properties-glass-how-light-and-glass-interact

Which includes this graph:
[image: Glass absorption]

And on this graph it would appear red light with a wavelength longer than 660 nm is not absorbed at all (zero absorption).

700 nm is still visible light, red, and the graph clearly shows zero absorption.

So I am not sure my initial explanation was the right one.

How glass is destroyed by light it does not absorb?

Comment: Looking on a linear scale is not sufficient. For intense enough light, and absorption coefficient of $10^{-6}$ suffices.

Comment: And? What about glass?

Comment: What about it? There likely is measurable absorption in the red, it just doesn't show on that plot. Hit it with enough power and bad things could happen.

Comment: Yeah well that's the whole point of my question. If you can provide a citation or an explanation about glass actually having a non null absorption, that would be an answer.

Comment: Try https://www.google.com/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=&ved=2ahUKEwjQo-fY-8vvAhVmAZ0JHXWVAsYQFjACegQIExAD&url=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.schott.com%2Fd%2Fadvanced_optics%2Fe434285e-65f6-4f21-a1b8-af282e17629c%2F1.5%2Fschott_tie-35_transmittance_of_optical_glass_us.pdf&usg=AOvVaw39HA1oA07n7H86vzTitnd_ to start, for example. Glasses are not perfect - there are defects. Even in single crystals there are defect states. Long-haul fiber losses may get measured in dB/km, but there are still losses to overcome.

Comment: Ok. I cannot say your PDF is very clear (figure 2-1 does not show the absorption level at the bottom of the curve k), but assuming your explanations are correct, this means I was right before I opened my web site and thought it was zero absorption.

Comment: You can assume that in any non-vacuum material there is no such thing as zero absorption...

Comment: @ptomato: what is the physical basis/proof behind this assertion?

Comment: There are no such things as ideal materials that always respond linearly. If there are atoms there to absorb light, then there is always a finite, even if small, absorption.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The extinction coefficient $k$ of glass for visible light is not zero, but approximately $10^{-8}$ (source: https://refractiveindex.info/?shelf=3d&book=glass&page=BK7). This implies that if enough light intensity is shined on a piece of glass, this might be absorbed to the point of heating it up and damaging it.

However, with very high intensities non-linear effects take place and might be dominant for transparent materials. Moreover, they enable non-thermal ablation (for example, see: https://tel.archives-ouvertes.fr/tel-01687375/document)

[image]

Comment: Very interesting contribution. Laser pulses directly breaking atomic bonds. I did not read the entire thesis but I intend to. Thanks.